# How can I test if a request returns a 404?

Tags: 404-page, 404

In my 404 template I am extending a layout template. Inside that layout template I want to hide a section use an `{% if craft.request... == 404 %}` test. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: I found a solution after I posted this... this seems to work but I am not sure if it is accurate.

`{% if not entry %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That solution is viable. You can just test to see if the entry or the template matches your 404 template/entry. If you routed everything correctly to display a 404 in case of error, you should be fine.